# Lucene search two parameter separated by space

Tags: java, lucene

I have lucene document like this

```
id   age   status
1    1 2    C G
2    2      G
3    2 1    C G  
4    2 5    C H
```

I did search like 
age: 2 AND status: 'G'
It returned the first three document. 
The problem is I did not want the third document with id:3. I only wanted the first two result. The data is arranged like this:

for id 1:
age 1 has status C
age 2 has status G

for id 3:
age 2 has status C
age 1 has status G

and I wanted age 2 with status G not C.. This is why id 3 is wrong for me.

how do I achieve this?
I am using java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For searches where 2+ attributes are bound together (like id 3 with age=2/status=C and age=1/status=G above), I think you need to bind them together in the index -- for example, adding a separate Lucene field *age_status*, so your Lucene documents would look like:

```
id   age   status  age_status
1    1 2    C G    1/C, 2/G
2    2      G      2/G
3    2 1    C G    2/C, 1/G 
4    2 5    C H    2/C, 5/H
```

(where '/' is the separator for age and status in *age_status* and 2+ values in *age_status* are shown with delimiting commas). This would let you search on `age_status:2/G`, yielding only Lucene documents id=1 and id=2 as search hits.

Comment: I don't want to re-index lucene. Is there a solution without re-indexing? is there a problem if I reindex?